# Why only projective varieties can be Kahler?

Tags: kahler-manifolds

Say we have a complex variety given by:

$$x^5+y^4+3=0$$

with $(x,y)\in \mathbb{C}^2$. Then apparently this is not a Kähler surface. (Or is it?) But if we do the projective completion:

$$x^5+y^4z+3z^5=0$$

With $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{PC}^2$ then this is a Kähler surface as all complex projective varieties in complex-projective space are Kähler as ["Every smooth complex projective variety"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4hler_manifold) is Kähler.

But the second case is just the first case with extra points `at infinity'.

So how can you have a complex structure on the second case but not on the first? The second is just the first projected onto the hyper-plane $z=1$ with some points projected to points at infinity

The first case is non-compact but this does not seem to be a condition of Kähler surfaces. Why is the first case not called Kähler also?

Comment: What makes you think that a smooth affine variety is not Kahler (when equipped with the restriction of the flat metric)?

Comment: I read it in this comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108307/are-complex-varieties-kahler-algebraic-non-projective-complex-manifolds I read somewhere which said most complex varieties are not Kahler only projective ones. But I got confused because I can turn any variety into a projective one by projective completion

Comment: You misunderstood what you have read, they only discussed compact complex manifolds. Read a textbook on Kahler geometry instead.

Comment: @MoisheKohan OK. Sorry for asking math questions in a math forum 

Comment: There is nothing to be sorry about, however, MO and MSE are not substitutes for a systematic learning.